# Обработка двух событий скриптом при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: c#, unity3d

В наличии имеется вот такой скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Audiou2 : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioClip Audi;
    public AnimationClip a;
    public GameObject As;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,105,81,81),""))
        {
            audio.clip = Audi;   
            audio.Play();
        }   
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,105,81,81),""))
        {
            As.animation.Play(a.name);  
        }
    }
}
```

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, которая высвечивается на экране, скрипт запускал одновременно воспроизведение аудиофайла и включал анимацию. Как возможно реализовать данные действия скрипта?

Answer (score 1):

Либо так

```
void OnGUI() { 
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,105,81,81),"")) {
        audio.clip = Audi;
        audio.Play(); 
        As.animation.Play(a.name);
    } 
}
```

Либо перейдите уже на UI. Делаете паблик метод

```
public void Activation(){
    audio.clip = Audi;
    audio.Play(); 
    As.animation.Play(a.name);
}
```

а в инспекторе кидаете нужной кнопке этот скрипт и выбираете метод Activation

Comment: Скрипт включает или анимацию или аудиофайл (что первым в скрипте напишешь) Но не все сразу одновременно.

Comment: @Kokoc2634 может у вас просто анимация раньше/позже начинается чем время, когда звук должен произойти? Тогда у аудио просто ставите нужную задержку и всё. Но отыграть они должны почти одновременно.......попробуйте вместо `Play` сделать `PlayOneShot`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Еще вопрос. Скрипт запускает анимацию при нажатии на кнопку. Если еще раз нажать (сразу же) на кнопку, анимация не начнется сначала, а будет продолжаться та, которая не закончилась. Можно ли заставить проигрывать анимацию сначала при нажатии на кнопку?
К примеру. Есть анимация, которая догоняет объект. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, анимация проигрывалась сначала (в первой точке) и не приходилось ждать, когда она завершится (дойдет до последней точки), чтобы снова ее можно было запустить.

Comment: для этого сначала проверяешь играет ли анимация, если да, то останавливаешь и запускаешь снова
if(animation.isPlaying) {
animation.Stop;
animation.Play(a.name);
}
если не помог Stop (что странно) , то придется отключить и снова включить аниматор

Comment: @Kokoc2634 зависит от того что за анимацию вы используете.... если `Animator` - то есть перегруженный метод `public void Play(string stateName, int layer = -1, float normalizedTime = float.NegativeInfinity);`   то есть он говорит буквально играй анимацию такую-то, в таком-то слое и с такого-то момента....... то есть например можете написать  `anim.Play("My Animation", -1, 0f);` и всё... а в 3d   в Animation наверное что-то подобное есть.... https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html  `public bool Play(string animation, PlayMode mode = PlayMode.StopSameLayer);` как раз

Comment: Не совсем понял как указать в скрипте нужную анимацию, которую нужно остановить...
public bool Play(string animation, PlayMode mode = PlayMode.StopSameLayer);
Как работает эта переменная? Что нужно указывать в строке анимации (string animation)?

Comment: @Kokoc2634 имя анимации. например `Walk` или `Idle` или `MySuperAnimation` и т.д.

Comment: Как будет код выглядеть, если название анимации "doorPovorot2".
Я здесь пишу что-то не так...
public bool Play(doorPovorot2 animation, PlayMode mode = PlayMode.StopSameLayer);

Comment: @Kokoc2634 вы зачем-то пишите объявление метода..... а надо реализацию ..... `As.animation.Play("doorPovorot2", PlayMode.StopSameLayer);`

Comment: Анимация все равно не останавливается, когда проигрывается.
И есть ошибки в коде:
using UnityEngine;
public class Audiou2 : MonoBehaviour {
public AudioClip Audi; 
public bool gal;
public AnimationClip a;
public GameObject As;
 
 void OnGUI()
{
 if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,105,81,81),""))
{
audio.clip = Audi;   
audio.Play();
   {
if(As.animation.Play.isPlaying)
    {
As.animation.Play("doorPovorot2", PlayMode.StopSameLayer);   
   }
   }  
  }
  
 }
}